# Google apps script server side data array not showing up in html page

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Why I am not able to get the value from server side to html side.

my log shows from server side that my array has data.

But when I try to check the same in Html alert it shows `null`

Here is my server side code which works completely fine :-

```
function getmytask()

{
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxx-xxxx');
  var sh = ss2.getSheetByName('Task-data');
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 
  var lastR = sh.getLastRow();
  var data = sh.getRange("A2:H"+lastR).getValues();
  
  let dataArray = data.filter(function(item){return item[0]==email || item[1] == email;})
  Logger.log(dataArray)  
  return dataArray;

}
```

This perfectly shows result in log example `[[a,b,c],[x,y,z],[p,q,r]]`

However, when I try to check the data at HTML page it shows `null` value. here is my client side script:-

```
<script>
  
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updatemytask).getmytask();

  });
 
 // document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',addmytask);

  function updatemytask(dataArray)
  {
  
  alert(dataArray)
   }
</script>
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed `var data = sh.getRange("A2:H"+lastR).getValues();` to `var data = sh.getRange("A2:H"+lastR).getDisplayValues();` and it started showing up. But unable to find the reason why.